# Is my test circuit correct for digipot DS1804?

Tags: digital-potentiometer

I want to test my DS1804 digital potentiometer on breadboard. Ohmmeter shows about 25 kohm between H and L or W. I thought it will go down with this circuit when I push button but it doesn't work (resistance stays at 25 kohm). I connected +5 V on U/D but it's same.

Where is my mistake?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwoo46.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R1 should be connected to the /INC terminal, and the switch should be connected between the /INC terminal and Ground.  This will ensure that the /INC terminal is a High unless the switch is closed.

Your circuit leaves /INC in an undetermined state when the switch is open, and High when the switch is closed.  The wiper position will only be incremented or decremented when the /INC input changes from High to Low.

To move the wiper towards the H terminal, the Up/Down input must be High.  When Up/Down is Low, the wiper moves toward the L terminal.

The resistance between H and L does not change - only the resistance between the wiper (W) and either H or L changes. W->H will decrease and W->L will increase as the wiper position is incremented.